# Using case to select field based on value of another field

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a database three fields: booking type, booking num and booking date. Some values are

```
 Bookingtype Bookingnum date
 main        0001       10-11-15
 main        0002       09-11-15
 sub         0002a      12-12-15
```

i need to write a select statement for the date for each record. But when the booking type is sub it should get the date from the main booking date. in this case booking 2a should have date 09-11-5..I'm using postgres 9.3 and have simplified the fields to make it easier for others to understand what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your main numbers are always the first 4 characters of `Bookingnum` (a clear definition is missing):

```
SELECT b.Bookingtype, b.Bookingnum
     , COALESCE(main.date, b.date) AS date
FROM   bookings b
LEFT   JOIN bookings main ON b.Bookingtype = 'sub'
                         AND main.Bookingnum = left(b.Bookingnum, 4);
```

I would consider a [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) column (self-reference) to the main row.